# How to plot a multivariate function with known coefficients using -scatter3d-

Tags: r, plot, graphics, scatter3d

I am trying to use R to plot a function that takes the form:

$$z=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x+\beta_{2}x^{2}+\beta_{3}y+\beta_{4}y^{2}+\beta_{5}x*y$$

Where I have numerical values for all the $\beta$'s. I can't seem to find an example of using the the functional form of -scatter3d- and I am not running a regression within R nor plotting the series of z, x, and y.

I currently have

```
scatter3D(df$z=0.0279x-0.0000188x_sq+0.0422y-0.00708y_sq-0.000181x_y, df)
```

And haven't even added anything else to it because I get an error message:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "scatter3D(df$z="
```

So I am assuming it is a syntax problem but can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: Side note: why doesn't Stack Overflow render LaTeX like other sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

You won't be able to plot 4 continuous variables against a single dependent on only 2 axes.

Formulas follow the pattern `y ~ x + z` so change your `=` to a `~`.

You don't need a `df$` in front of any variable since you specify the data with the `..., df` part.

Formula's don't accept coefficients but you can easily change them in the original data frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100,5,1),
           y=rnorm(100,50,1),
           z=rnorm(100,500,1))

df$x_sq<-0.000188*(df$x)^2
df$y_sq<-0.0708*(df$y)^2
  df$y2<-0.0422*(df$y)
  df$x2<-0.0279*(df$x)

   scatter3d(z~x2+y2,df)
```

Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow

If you want a surface, not a scatter, then modify coefficients in this:

```
  x <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 50)  
  y <- x 
  zf<-function(x,y){1*x^2+1*x-0.1*y^2-0.1*y+0.1*y*1*x}
  z <- outer(x, y, zf)
             surface3d(x,y,z)
```

Comment: How would I include the interaction effect? (i.e. the effect of x on z varies with different levels of y when looking at the first order partial derivative). Re: latex; that is sad